# How to break apart the Linq expression inside an Any clause

Tags: c#, .net, linq, wcf-data-services, odata

I am trying to make a modular Linq query (to an OData source).

This is a simplified version of my query:

```
// Any clause that I want to be modular
Func<Encounter, bool> orderAnyClause = x => x.OrderName.StartsWith("Order 00");

// Query using the any clause
var result = entities.Customers.Where(cust=> cust.Orders.Any(orderAnyClause));

// A method to do the selection.  It works just fine.
IQueryable<SearchSelectionResult> selectedResults = SelectResults(result); 

// This throws the exception shown below
var list = selectedResults.ToList();
```

This all compiles fine, but when I run it my any clause causes this exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.

I know it is my any clause because if I embed the the clause in the statement, it all works fine.

**Why am I getting this error?  And how can I break this statement out and not get the error?**

---

**Update: Using an Expression**

I tried to use an expression like this:

```
Expression<Func<Encounter, bool>> orderAnyClause = 
                                      x => x.OrderName.StartsWith("Order 00");
```

And I get the following compile time error message:

```
Instance argument: cannot convert from System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceCollection<ODataComponetizedQueriesTest.MyEntities.Order>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<ODataComponetizedQueriesTest.MyEntities.Order>'
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try defining orderAnyClause like this:

```
Expression<Func<Encounter, bool>> orderAnyClause = 
                                        x => x.OrderName.StartsWith("Order 00");
```

I didn't test it, but the way query comprehension works (and based on the error), it wouldn't be able to do anything with it unless it gets it as an expression.

Comment: I tried that and it gives a compile time error.  (I updated my question with the error message.)

Comment: Is the Orders property IEnumerable? I'm assuming it is. The signature of the Enumerable.Any extension method does not take an Expression<Func<T, bool>>, so you won't be able to use it. Instead, you would need to create the expressions using Expression.Lamba, Expression.Call, etc, which is all those extension methods do anyway. Or you could make the type of Orders IQueryable<T> as someone suggests below.

Answer (score 0):

Your `IQueryable` needs to work with [*expression trees*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) in order to convert the query - in other words, it needs to have a view of the code as data, rather than just as executable code.

Now I'm not 100% sure this will work, but I'd *hope* that you could use:

```
Expression<Func<Encounter, bool>> orderAnyClause =
    x => x.OrderName.StartsWith("Order 00");
```

... and then keep the same code. That way your `orderByClause` variable refers to an expression tree, not a delegate. Now it's possible that that won't work - because you're using it in another lambda expression here:

```
cust => cust.Orders.Any(orderAnyClause)
```

... and that lambda expression will *also* be converted to an expression tree. It really depends on what the OData provider does with it. You *may* need to write a method to do funky stuff to build up the `cust.Orders.Any(orderAnyClause)` - but it's worth trying the simple way first.

Comment: I tried that, but I get a compile error with that.  (See my updated question for the Error).

Comment: @Vaccano: Do you get that error *on that line* or later? It seems an odd line to get the error on...

Comment: It is on the line where I try to use the orderAnyClause (The second line of code in my example.)

Comment: @Vaccano: Right, so what's the type of `cust.Orders`? You really need that to be an `IQueryable<Encounter>` of some kind...

Comment: That must be why this does not work.  WCF Data Services exposes that as a DataServiceCollection which inherits from ObservableCollection.  I am guessing that this will just not work with OData.

Comment: @Vaccano: I suspect so. You could *try* calling `AsQueryable()` which will remove the compile-time error - but I doubt that it will work at execution time :(